# What does these lines of CSS do?

Tags: css, superfish

In the following lines (from superfish):

```
ul.sf-navbar .current ul ul {
    top: -999em;
}
```

Does `top: -999em` have a special meaning? Why is the top set to a value that is not visible in the browser?

Comment: Someone is using an oddball property when there are better alternatives, that's what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's purpose is solely to keep any second-tier and higher menus from appearing automatically when the first-tier menu is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

That would be so the subnavigation is "hidden" until it's parent is hovered over, then it will be shown.

Answer (score 2):

I presume this is a drop-down menu that is set beyond the visible bounds using `top: -999em;` so that it can be changed via javascript/css to appear.